# C++ Vector value isn't assigned

Tags: c++, vector

First off, yes I'm new to C++ vectors.

Now my question is, why do you think my vector is empty?

I have a global variable:

```
vector<int> parentVector;
```

Now, since it's a global variable, and I don't know what size should it be, only later into the program, I do this at some point:

```
//numberOfNodes = 8 in current example
parentVector.reserve(numberOfNodes);
```

And a little later, I try to assign a value to the first element of the vector, but it doesn't work:

```
parentVector[0] = -1;
```

And I also do the following, which doesn't assign any value either:

```
//nextNode.node and currentNode.node is between the range of 1 - 8, thus the - 1.
parentVector[nextNode.node - 1] = currentNode.node - 1;
```

**Edit: Thank you for your answers, resize() worked.**

Comment: either use `resize` with `[]` accessor, or simply use `push_back`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reserving space in a vector using `std::vector::reserve` is not the same as adding elements to it. After reserving the vector is still empty. Use `std::vector::resize` instead.